# Gradle manage plugins on generated POM using maven plugin

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm on a team where maven and gradle is used, and I have a gradle project that wants to generate a functioning pom file so that our maven users can keep using maven.

I have solved this problem so far as generating a pom with appropriate dependencies as follows:

build.gradle excerpt:

```
task createpom(dependsOn: 'build') << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}

build.finalizedBy(createpom)
```

This works well for creating just the dependencies on a pom, but gradle's maven plugin API does not seem to support defining the contents of the `<build>` tag, which I need to import certain plugins for a successful maven build.

In short, I need one of the following:

- Postprocessing the build tag into the generated POM.  I could do it by manipulating the file directly, but prefer not to.
- Splitting the POM into two parts, one with only gradle managed dependencies, and one with only the human managed things.  Unfortunately, I don't see any means of arbitrarily naming a pom dependency by file name; only solutions that involve adding a pom only project or using multi-module builds, neither of which I like considering that I have no need for a shareable parent pom or multi-module project.  I would much prefer something akin to `<import>my/arbitrary/path/buildstuff.xml</import>`, since all a really need to do is glue two halves of a POM for the same project/lifecycle together.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this other than what I've found so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the XML tweaking solution, which proved to be far more elegant than I anticipated.  Implementation involved adding an unmanaged pom to my project directory to hold the human-managed parts of the build, and modifying my createpom task as such:

```
task createpom(dependsOn: 'build') << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version
        }
    }.withXml {
        def templateXml = (new XmlParser()).parse('pom-unmanaged.xml')
        asNode().append(templateXml.build)
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}
```

`pom-unmanaged.xml` takes the form of a typical pom, minus the bits that my gradle build script generates.